# Execute a promise until a condition is met (within a while loop)

Tags: typescript, promise, protractor

I want to encapsulate a promise within a while loop, so that my method is executed until a condition is met.  I've tried to implement this, however I end up with infinite promises generated until a stack overflow occurs.

I want to implement something like the following in TypeScript:

```
while (responseSuccess === false) {
    myClass.executeScript.then((thisWasSuccessful: boolean) => {
         responseSuccess = thisWasSuccessful;
    });
```

I know that this is a little unconventional, but the script I have created is a request to the server that the application normally executes.  It does not always return a success the first time, or *n* times (not something that I can change).

Comment: `while(!await myClass.executeScript()) ;`?

Comment: If you use `then` with callbacks, you need to use a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use await operator.

```
while (responseSuccess === false) {
  responseSuccess = await myClass.executeScript;
});
```

PS: You should use TS 2.1 or higher to target ES5

Answer (score 2):

Well, I agree with the other answers, it would be really easy to implement this using the async/await operators. The latest stable release of Typescript, 2.1.4, can already transpile the async/await code to ES5.

If you really need to do this using only the standard Promise, maybe something like this would be enough?

```
this.executeAsync.then(() => {
  // after while loop code
});

private executeAsync(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((callback) => this.executeAsyncLoop(callback));
}

private executeAsyncLoop(callback: () => void): void {
  myClass.executeScript.then((thisWasSuccessful: boolean) => {
     if(!thisWasSuccessful) executeAsyncLoop(callback);
     else callback();
  });
}
```

I don't have an environment to test this code right now, so I apologize if it isn't working.

Comment: When I implemented this, it got stuck on the myClass.executeScript() and never got to executing anything after .then()

Comment: @fuzzii Well, it's difficult to know what would be the problem, since this is your script code. If this part of the code is executing and the callback inside the then() is not being called, there could be something wrong with your script not calling the promise callback correctly.
You could isolate this just calling your script and making sure the callback inside the then() is called.